# Firestore rules - Acces document id in resource

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm currently migrating a Realtime Database into Firestore and came across some questions. My rules are set as below:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

      match /users/ {
          allow read
          match /{$user} {
              allow create: if isAuthenticated(request) && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)) === false
              allow update: if isAuthenticated(request) && request.auth.id === resource.data;

              match /notifications/{$notification} {
                  allow write: if request.auth.id === resource.data
              }
          }

      } 

   }
}
function isAuthenticated(req) {
    return request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

I want to secure updating for users only if `$user` is the same as the auth ID (`request.auth.id`). The same goes for notifications. Is it possible to access `$user` inside the notifications rule?

Comment: Have you tried it? Seems like a simple thing you can check yourself. Or have you already tried it and are you getting errors/unexpected results?

Answer (score 0):

The rules are scoped, so you can access variables from a higher level in a nested scope.

In your case the `allow write` rule has access to `$user`, and `$notification`.